# Multiple the variable passed in pause command in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to make pause command dynamic like define it first and multiple or divide it (in shortest form) in test as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Selenium docs mention that Javascript can be used in Selenium IDE in two ways. With script-parameters (storeEval etc) and with non-script parameters (direct javascript). The easier solution to  your problem is using non-script parameters in your selenium-ide commands.

Simply replace `${delay}/2` with `javascript{storedVars['delay']/2}` and so on.. as shown in attached screenshot. You can also use `echo` command to verify if this solution is working as expected.

[image]

For more details, I recommend reading official selenium docs:

[Selenium IDE official documentation on using javascript](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#javascript-and-selenese-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of storeEval command in Selenium IDE. Using it you can add, divide, multiply any variable with desired value and then use it.

Command: storeEval
Target: storedVars['delay']*2
Value: doubleDelay

```
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>delay</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['delay']*2</td>
    <td>doubleDelay</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${doubleDelay}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
```

[reference for storeEval](http://www.questionselenium.com/2012/10/echo-storeeval-and-storedvars.html)

Comment: Please dont post links but post an example which fits the question instead.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Details added now.